# SliceContourPlot3D combinations with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, plotting

I am trying to visualize 4D data, 3 space and one time, i.e., f(x,y,z,t). Using `SliceContourPlot3D` looks like one of the best options. And I did the following and it works fine.

```
h[x_, y_, z_, t_] := Sin[x] Cos[y] Sin[z] Exp[t];

 Manipulate[
SliceContourPlot3D[
h[x, y, z, 
t], {{"XStackedPlanes", {i}}, {"YStackedPlanes", {j}}, 
{"ZStackedPlanes", {k}}}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 
10}, {z, 0, 15}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 13, Blue], Style["y", 13, Blue], 
Style["z", 13, Blue]}], {{t, 0, Style["Time", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 
1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{i, 0, 
Style["zy plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 5, 1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{j, 0, 
Style["zx plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k, 0, 
Style["xy plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 15, 1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

But I would like to able to give an option to visualize only one (xy or zy or zx) or only two planes (xy and zy ..).  I tried nested `Manipulate` to have a toggle bar it didn't work. I tried the following and it is not working. I also realized that the nested if statements are not elegant. Any suggestions?

```
Panel[Framed[Module[{xyzPlanes = {1, 2}}, Column[{
 Row[{Style["Planes of Interest ", 14, Blue, Editable -> False], 
   TogglerBar[
    Dynamic[xyzPlanes], {1 -> "xy-Plane", 2 -> " yz-Plane", 
     3 -> "xz-Plane"}]}],
 Row[{
   Res =
    If[
     MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 1] == True && 
      MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 2] == False && 
      MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 3] == False,
     Manipulate[
      SliceContourPlot3D[
       h[x, y, z, t], {"XStackedPlanes", {i}}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 
        10}, {z, 0, 10}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
       AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 13, Blue], Style["y", 13, Blue], 
         Style["z", 13, Blue]}], {{t, 0, Style["Time", 12, Blue]},
        0, 10, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{i, 0, 
        Style["zy plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ContinuousAction -> False],
     If[
      MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 1] == False && 
       MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 2] == True && 
       MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 3] == False,

      Manipulate[
       SliceContourPlot3D[
        h[x, y, z, t], {"YStackedPlanes", {j}}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0,
          10}, {z, 0, 10}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", , 
        AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 13, Blue], Style["y", 13, Blue], 
          Style["z", 13, Blue]}], {{t, 0, 
         Style["Time", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{j, 0, 
         Style["y plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ContinuousAction -> False],

      MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 1] == True && 
       MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 2] == True && 
       MemberQ[xyzPlanes, 3] == False,
      Manipulate[

       SliceContourPlot3D[
        h[x, y, z, 
         t], {{"XStackedPlanes", {i}}, {"YStackedPlanes", {j}}, \
        {"ZStackedPlanes", {k}}}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 15}, 
        ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
        PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
        AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 13, Blue], Style["y", 13, Blue], 
          Style["z", 13, Blue]}], {{t, 0, 
         Style["Time", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{i, 0, 
         Style["zy plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 5, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{j, 0, 
         Style["zx plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ContinuousAction -> False]

      ]]}],
     Row[{Style[" ", 12, Red], 
      InputField[Dynamic[Res], FieldSize -> {50, 35}]}, Spacer[15]]


      }]]], Background -> Lighter[Gray, .6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[SliceContourPlot3D[h[x, y, z, t], 
  planes /.  {{} | "XStackedPlanes" -> {"XStackedPlanes", {i}}, 
    "YStackedPlanes" -> {"YStackedPlanes", {j}},
    "ZStackedPlanes" -> {"ZStackedPlanes", {k}}}, 
  {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 15}, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 13, Blue], Style["y", 13, Blue],  Style["z", 13, Blue]}],
 {{planes, "XStackedPlanes", Style["planes", 12, Blue]}, 
     {"XStackedPlanes", "YStackedPlanes", "ZStackedPlanes"}, TogglerBar},
 {{t, 0, Style["Time", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{i, 0, Style["zy plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "XStackedPlanes"]}, 
 {{j, 0, Style["zx plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "YStackedPlanes"]}, 
 {{k, 0, Style["xy plane position", 12, Blue]}, 0, 15, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "ZStackedPlanes"]}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, it is so clean.