# Solve / brute-force for parameters that drive a function to zero at specified points

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization, replacement, parametric-functions

Edit: *Made question a lot easier to read.*

**Simple example**. 
 - Consider $p(x,y,z,t) = e^t(ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2)$ and I seek the values of $a,b,c$ which make $p\approx0$ at the point $(x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta,m,t)$ for all $t\ge0$ where $0 < \theta 
\le 2\pi$. A non-trivial solution will be $(a,b,c)=\{(m/r)^2,(m/r)^2,-1\}$. How could I have found this in Mathematica?

**Actual problem description:**

- I have 3 real-valued functions $f(x,y,z,t)$, $g(x,y,z,t)$, $h(x,y,z,t)$ which contain some **non-zero** parameters/coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ .
- At ***carefully selected*** values of those parameters, the functions
  are each forced to be approximately zero **for all the points**
  parametrized by $(x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta,m,t)$, where $0 \le t$ with $0 < r \le R$ and $0 < \theta \le 2\pi$. How do
  I brute-force or solve for the parameters which drive those functions
  to zero?
- In this question, by zero I mean some number $\epsilon$ such that $abs(\epsilon) > 10^{−5}$

**Sample functions (the actual functions are much longer and complicated):**

Find non-zero $a,b,d$ such that *at all the parametrized points* as defined above, then $f\approx0$ && $g\approx0$ && $\textrm{Norm}[h]\approx0$ where

```
f = 1/2 a^2 E^(-2 d^2 t) (E^(2 a x)+E^(2 a y)+E^(2 a z)+2 E^(a (y+z)) Cos[d x+a z] Sin[a x+d y]+2 E^(a (x+y)) Cos[a y+d z] Sin[d x+a z]+2 E^(a (x+z)) Cos[a x+d y] Sin[a y+d z]);
g = (a^2+b^2+ab)*Exp[2*(a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2)*t]*(Exp[a*(x-y)+b*(x-z)] + Exp[a*(y-z)+b*(y-x)] + Exp[a*(z-x)+b*(z-y)]);
h = {a E^(-d^2 t) (E^(a z) Cos[a x+d y]+E^(a x) Sin[a y+d z]),a E^(-d^2 t) (E^(a x) Cos[a y+d z]+E^(a y) Sin[d x+a z]),a E^(-d^2 t) (E^(a y) Cos[d x+a z]+E^(a z) Sin[a x+d y])};
```

**What I have tried:**

1. `ReplaceAll` for the variables $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, enforce constraints on $z,\theta,r$ and $t$ then use `Minimize`. [This doesn't work, Mathematica simply returns the input command](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217238/minimize-not-working-it-returns-the-same-input-command?noredirect=1&lq=1). I have also asked this on another question. e.g.

   `points = {x^2+y^2->r^2,x->r*Cos[\[Theta]],y->r*Sin[\[Theta]]};
    Minimize[{f /. points, 0 < z <= 200 && 0 <= \[Theta] < 2\[Pi] && t > 0}, {a,d}]`
2. `ReplaceAll` for the variables, and then `SolveAlways` for $z,r,\theta$ and $t$ in the constraints. I also tried `Reduce`. Neither worked e.g. for `SolveAlways`,

   `fpoints = Simplify[f, {x^2 + y^2 -> r^2, x->r*Cos[theta], y->r*Sin[theta]}];
   gpoints = Simplify[g, {x^2 + y^2 -> r^2, x->r*Cos[theta], y->r*Sin[theta]}];
   hpoints = Simplify[h, {x^2 + y^2 -> r^2, x->r*Cos[theta], y->r*Sin[theta]}];
   SolveAlways[fpoints==0 && gpoints == 0 && hpoints == 0 && t >= 0 && 0 < theta <= 2*Pi && m >= z > 0,{theta,r,z,t}]`
3. Manual brute-force process. I tried fixing some parameters (my random guesses), evaluating the functions and using `FindMinValue` and `FindMaxValue` for all theta, t and z e.g. 
   `fpoints = Simplify[f, {x^2 + y^2 -> r^2, x->r*Cos[theta], y->r*Sin[theta]}];
   FindMinValue[{fpoints /.{r->1,a->1,b->1,c->1/10,d->-1/100,e->25}, {0 <= z < m && 0 <= theta < 2*Pi}}, {theta,t,z}
   FindMaxValue[{fpoints /.{r->1,a->1,b->1,c->1/10,d->-1/100,e->25}, {0 <= z < m && 0 <= theta < 2*Pi}}, {theta,t,z}`

   (For ℎ I did the FindMinValue on Norm[hpoints] after the ReplaceAll). By randomly changing the parameters manually, I can occasionally obtain cases in which FindMinValue and FindMaxValue give me numerical zeros e.g. `FindMinValue` gives −6.07768∗10−7 and `FindMaxValue` gives me 5.52429∗10−8. Then I move on to the other functions and see if I get numerical zero for $g$ and $h$ as well at *those same parameters*. This isn't always working out so far. Since I am changing parameters manually I am sure I am definitely missing the sweet spot in between the parameter values.

Comment: A smaller but complete example that shows the issue would be quite helpful.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! Does the smaller example I included help?

Comment: Yes, it's a good example. Unfortunately it gives me the feeling that the only solution will be trivial: factor the expressions and see if each have factors free of `{x,y,z,t}`. If so, solve for them being zero.

Comment: Yeah, the approach doesn't work in this case. I program in general but I am relatively new to Mathematica so I am struggling here. e.g. I don't know why "Minimize" simply returns the input command to me. Also, I think there might be some methods I am not familiar with - and I have been searching the help guide to no avail. Any pointers will be very welcome.

Comment: Maybe `NMinimize` instead of `Minimize`? Also, if there are terms that decay rapidly, a series expansion centered at the origin might give a reasonable multivariate polynomial that is more amenable to analysis.

Comment: It was not clear to me that `m` and `r` are (apparently) adjustable rather than free parameters. So expanding as a series in `theta` and equating coefficients is perhaps a viable way forward.

Comment: Thanks again! Actually I can adjust $r$ in my problem and "fix" it by scaling (it's just a radius), but technically this should hold for all $m$ (i.e. for all every lateral point on the 3D cylinder in the third axis). I was hoping to simplify the problem by considering a fixed value of $m$ and going from there. Two bounties and no answers so I am starting to think maybe it's too hard in general for Mathematica.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau When expanding as a power series do you think I can choose any arbitrarily large order?

Comment: If there is a solution that makes the expression zero then it should work for any order.

Comment: Are you sure that such a solution exists in your actual problem?

Comment: @Chris Yes, the physics of the problem indicates that the functions *must* all be zero at those points parametrized in a 3D cylinder, I only need to find the coefficients to make it happen. This is a step in the "method of manufactured solutions" for a set of PDEs.

Comment: Also, are you expecting an analytical solution or perhaps it can only be solved numerically?

Comment: An analytical solution would have given me some more flexibility but based on my deadlines at this point I will gladly take a numerical one instead, if it satisfies all constraints. Thanks!

P.S. I suspect that a brute-force approach similar to (3) should work, but I don't know how to brute-force solutions in Mathematica.

Comment: @Cogicero You did not formulate the problem with the necessary number of constrains . There is a trivial solution there `a=b=c=d=e=0`. If we get a solution to this problem, then this will not help solve your real problem.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, you're right, I should have added that $a,b,c,d,e$ are non-zero. I am seeking non-trivial solutions to the physical problem. I will modify the question to add that.

Comment: @Cogicero What do you mean? Is $a=b=c=d=e=10^{-200}$ non-zero?

Comment: My bad, I didn't mention the precision. By zero I mean a number $\epsilon$ such that $abs(\epsilon) > 1e^{-5}$, say. I hope we're on the same page now. These parameters are non-trivial physical quantities from my problem. In a bid to make the question easier to approach, I had done away with some definitions and contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea on your actual problem, but your simple example can be solved by choosing a few arbitrary values of `θ`:

```
FullSimplify[
  Solve[0 == E^t (a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2)
    /. {x -> r Cos[θ], y -> r Sin[θ], z -> m} /. θ -> {0, 1, 2}, {a, b}]]
(* {{a -> -((c m^2)/r^2), b -> -((c m^2)/r^2)}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Please you post this answer on the other bounty question (which this fully answers): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217238/ so I can award it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that one.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to start with visualizations. This hard to visualize.

There are two types of functions in this question: `Exp` and `Sin` and `Cos`.

For f:

a dominate the Exp so has to be taken arbitrarily from the Exp condition. If a is big, then for large {x,y,z} the conditions can not be met at all. The Sin and Cos terms do not cancel out the exponential divergence at all. For smaller a the are then arbitrarily many potential minima. So the x,y,z-ranges have to be constrained to find minimum.

A meaningful approach are visualizations like:

```
With[{z = 0}, 
 Manipulate[
  Plot3D[E^(2 a x) + E^(2 a y) + E^(2 a z) + 
    2 E^(a (y + z)) Cos[d x + a z] Sin[a x + d y] + 
    2 E^(a (x + y)) Cos[a y + d z] Sin[d x + a z] + 
    2 E^(a (x + z)) Cos[a x + d y] Sin[a y + d z], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6,
     6}], {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}, {d, 0, 2}]]
```

If did put in sliders for a,b and d just set the other coordinates zero.

This is a z=0 cut through the four-dimensional function.

It did put t=0 first since this is only an amplitude to the combination of trigonometrical function with exponential coefficients.

For most triples of a,b and d the function f looks like an egg tray. The minima are a zig-zag. The maxima grow like the exponential functions suggest.

The use of Series is a nice help. To zeros order this results in a nice complicated polynomial in a,b and d.

Since everything does not really work of the shelve from Mathematica good old knowledge must be applied. The only method are Lagrange multipliers as additional dimensions. One for each f,g and h and for the minimization constrains: $f\approx0$ && $g\approx0$ && $\textrm{Norm}[h]\approx0$.

Simpler version in Mathematica are presented in many questions here on Mathematica.stackexchange. These are easily generalized and coded for this case. But take under consideration the is five-dimensional from the definition of the function with Exp and trigonometrics and there are there conditions to be met.

Take for example this:  [How can I implement the method of Lagrange multipliers to find constrained extrema?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36847/how-can-i-implement-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-to-find-constrained-extre?rq=1)

This question goes a bit further in visualization:
[4D Table, Slider limitation and plotting ListSliceContourPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186461/4d-table-slider-limitation-and-ploting-listslicecontourplot3d)

It is hard to decide whether the solutions will be maxima or minima without a visual idea. The only point is the this will be extrema in the complete space. Since no values for a, b or d are given numerical simulation will not be easily find something.

The conditions are only given in a proximal form and not as equation is the main flaw.

Hope that solves the question so far.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, one needs to appreciate that there is no unique solution to the problem at hand, so one cannot ask Mathematica to find the expected answer. At best, it can find the relation between the **dependent variables** ($a,b,c$ in the simplified example) in terms of **independent variables** ($r,t,\theta,m$). Fortunately, this is quite doable.

The main function that we will be using is `Reduce`, which will give all possible cases for which given function is zero. We will then eliminate the possibilities which require independent variables to take specific values (such as $r=0$), as these cases are isolated solutions whereas we are interested in generalized solution. Finally, we will assume that the required inequalities for the solution is satisfied (such as $r\ne0$, which is actually a condition for OP's preferred answer as it involves $a=m^2/r^2$).

The code to do these is as follows:

```
ClearAll[solve];
Options[solve] = Options[FullSimplify];
solve[independentParameters_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{condition, replace},
   condition[a_, b_] := Table[FreeQ[Equal[a, b], i], {i, 
   Subsets[Alternatives @@ independentParameters, {Length[independentParameters] - 1}]}];
   replace = Equal[a_, b_] :> False /; (Or @@ condition[a, b]);
   FullSimplify[Reduce[# == 0] /. replace /. Unequal[a_, b_] -> True,
   Assumptions -> opts]
  ] &;
```

We can see it in action as follows:

```
p[a_, b_, c_][t_, x_, y_, z_] := Exp[t] (a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2);
p[a, b, c][t, r Sin[\[Theta]], r Cos[\[Theta]], m] // solve[{r, \[Theta], m, t}]
(* a + b Cot[\[Theta]]^2 + (c m^2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2)/r^2 == 0 *)
```

which gives the general solution:

> $$a+b \cot ^2(\theta )+\frac{c m^2 \csc ^2(\theta )}{r^2}=0$$

We can now fix any solution we like; for example, we can get OP's result back as follows:

```
a + b Cot[\[Theta]]^2 + (c m^2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2)/r^2 == 0 /. {c -> -1, b -> m^2/r^2} // FullSimplify
(* a == m^2/r^2 *)
```

The code as written is quite general and should work with other input. In particular, we did not make use of anything specific to the function $p(t,x,y,z)$. As an example, consider a similar yet modified function:

```
p2[a_, b_, c_][t_, x_, y_, z_] := Exp[2 t] (a x^4 + b y^4 + c z^4);
p2[a, b, c][t, r Sin[\[Theta]], r Cos[\[Theta]], m] // solve[{r, \[Theta], m, t}]
(* a + b Cot[\[Theta]]^4 + (c m^4 Csc[\[Theta]]^4)/r^4 == 0 *)
```

for which fixing
$$c=-1\;,b=\frac{m^4}{r^4}$$
gives us the answer
$$a=\frac{m^4 \left(\cot ^4(\theta )+\csc ^4(\theta )\right)}{r^4}$$

We can of course use the code for functions with other number of variables. For example:

```
p3[a_, b_, c_, d_][t_, x_, y_, z_, u_] := Exp[t] (a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 + d u^2);
p3[a, b, c, d][t, r Sin[\[Theta]], r Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], r Cos[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], m] // solve[{r, \[Theta], \[Phi], m, t}]
(* a + (d m^2 Csc[\[Theta]]^2)/r^2 + Cot[\[Theta]]^2 (c Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + b Sin[\[Phi]]^2) == 0 *)
```

for which fixing
$$b=c=\frac{m^2}{r^2}\;, d=-1$$
fixes
$$a=\frac{m^2}{r^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. Hmmm... I've been running it for the past 20 hours on my actual object function, and it's still running, so it's hard to tell if it's working out yet. Is there any way to break this down into parts to ensure it hasn't hung?

Comment: ANSWER PART 1: `Reduce` is extremely slow when it comes to complicated expressions, and should really not be used straightforwardly. Technically, it works and produce results but just takes forever (To see that the bottleneck is `Reduce`, forget about my code and just run `Reduce[f==0]` where `f` is your relevant function).

Comment: PART 2: I wrote the answer above for **sufficiently small** expressions;for larger ones,one should either come up with a problem-specific solutions(for example, in your simple example, the result can be chosen $\theta$ independent due to spherical symmetry and one can impose it in the code) or one should decompose the large expression into smaller ones and apply the code to small ones separately. For the latter, `Factor` can be handy: you can even write a small code, which factors a given expression into smaller ones, apply my function to each case, and return the results with an overall `Or`.

Comment: You're right. Reduce [f == 0, {a,b,c}] does run forever also (I had previously tried that). You'e obviously put in a lot of thought and I wish I could award this. I'm starting to think a brute-force search across a grid might be the only way out here. Such as this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218391

Comment: Well, thanks for your assistance. I will award the bounty even though this didn't work for me.